# How to get form validation active in Web Experience Toolkit 3.1 Lightbox

Tags: php, validation, toolkit

I'm currently working on a project that uses the [Web Experience Toolkit](http://wet-boew.github.io/v3.1-ci/index-en.html). I have a page with a table that's populated by an add button which opens a LightBox window (colorbox plugin) which has my form.

I've used both the standard Lightbox and the IFrame version. IFrame version is what I'm currently using because I figured it'd have the best luck and be easiest to develop everything in.

Currently the Code is functional as is....meaning window opens, form works, submit works, window closes and refreshes page.....However on the submit the Web Experience Toolkit doesn't work.

The validation that is shown is that of the browser. Which means instead of the label changing to demonstrate an error and the list of errors appearing above the form a tiny bubble shows up for a single error.

I've followed the documentation to the letter.

[Form Validation documentation](http://wet-boew.github.io/v3.1-ci/docs/ref/formvalid/formvalid-en.html)

Has anyone had any success applying the validation to the lightbox? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two part problem to this:

1. Loading the JQuery validation library twice from W.E.T. files

   1. Interfered with validation
2. Chrome and Firefox bug with Jquery Validator library that W.E.T. utilizes

   1. After much research discovered that this bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Solutions:

1. Load W.E.T. Jquery validation once

   1. This got the errors to display properly
2. Don't validate numbers

   1. The bug in the validator library is specific to numbers in Chrome and Firefox